# How can I export Next 13 project that use app/ route and some dynamic routes

Tags: react-redux, next.js13, next-auth

I'm really struggling with exporting my project to HTML, CSS, JS. I'm using Next Js 13, NextAuth, my language module is based on dynamic route.

I would like to export my project to mount it on a Tomcat server not running it as a server.

I used `"export": "next build && next export"` after I also used `output: "export"`,

This is my output when doing npm run build :

```
info  - Need to disable some ESLint rules? Learn more here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#disabling-rules
- info Linting
- info Collecting page data
- info Generating static pages (2/2)
- info Finalizing page optimization

Route (app)                                            Size     First Load JS
┌ ● /[lang]                                            20.9 kB         238 kB
├ ● /[lang]/auth/resetPassword                         4.25 kB         159 kB
├ ● /[lang]/auth/signIn                                4.7 kB          153 kB
├ ● /[lang]/auth/signUp                                4.91 kB         163 kB
├ ● /[lang]/profils                                    4.72 kB         153 kB
├ ● /[lang]/profils/company                            9.13 kB         169 kB
├ ● /[lang]/reviews                                    5.88 kB         152 kB
├ λ /[lang]/reviews/campaigns                          32.1 kB         217 kB
├ λ /[lang]/reviews/categories                         9.25 kB         168 kB
├ ● /[lang]/reviews/categories/[id]                    5.77 kB         162 kB
├ ● /[lang]/reviews/categories/[id]/offers             155 B          78.9 kB
└ ● /[lang]/reviews/categories/[id]/offers/[offer_id]  7.9 kB          170 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                          78.7 kB
  ├ chunks/596-8329f6164b666b1c.js                     26.2 kB
  ├ chunks/fd9d1056-20f694886ed3ffab.js                50.5 kB
  ├ chunks/main-app-5d2036a3d0662739.js                220 B
  └ chunks/webpack-75cb8772e4c22133.js                 1.85 kB

Route (pages)                                          Size     First Load JS
┌ ○ /404                                               184 B          76.8 kB
└ λ /api/auth/[...nextauth]                            0 B            76.6 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                          76.6 kB
  ├ chunks/framework-964c2d6016b0d731.js               45.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main-bfb68cd5b3fd6121.js                    29.5 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app-c39a67c97d2e85f6.js              197 B
  └ chunks/webpack-75cb8772e4c22133.js                 1.85 kB

ƒ Middleware                                           65.9 kB

λ  (Server)  server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
○  (Static)  automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
●  (SSG)     automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
```

[image: image of generate file]

Answer (score 1):

You have to follow below steps to export a static project. 
Beware you cannot use server side actions in this static project.

**Step-1:** Modify your next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    output: 'export',
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

**Step-2:** Modify scripts in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build && next export",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```

**Step-3:** Run `npm run build` and a folder named out will be generated in your project folder.

Comment: I follow exactly your step, and this is what I'm getting.


`- info Loaded env from C:\Users\my\path\.env
- warn "next export" is no longer needed when "output: export" is configured in next.config.js https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export
Export successful. Files written to C:\Users\my\path\out`


The build was successful but still it is not possible to run it with its plain JS CSS HTML, there is no index.html on the root of the build like what we got when we do the same for a react app.

Comment: there will be a folder named out in your project folder `(Files written to C:\Users\my\path\out)`